# 'User' object has no attribute 'is_staff'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-authentication

I am working with user authentication system where I created a user registration model using AbstractBaseUser. then I create super User using terminal . But when I go the admin and write email and password there . It gives me the error that: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_staff'

**My models.py file is**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager

SUBJECT_CHOICES = (
    ('math','Math'),
    ('physics','Physics'),
    ('chemistry','Chemistry'),
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name=None, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password")


        user_obj = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), full_name=full_name)
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self,email,full_name=None,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, full_name=full_name,password=password)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email, full_name=None,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, full_name=full_name, password=password)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    full_name       = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    sur_name        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=255 ,unique=True)
    choose_subject  = models.CharField(choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES , max_length=100)
    staff           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_stamp      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    object = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

**my forms.py file is**:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm): # A form for creation new user included all all the required fields including repeated password
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Enter Password' , widget=forms.PasswordInput )
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('full_name','sur_name','email','choose_subject')

    def clean_password2(self): # check that two password entries match or not

        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("password dont match")
        return password2

    def save(self , commit=True): #save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(RegisterForm , self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

        #user.active = False #send confirmation email
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**my views.py is**:

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = "users/register.html"
    success_url = '/register'
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to resolve this problem

Number one: create property method into your user model:

```
@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.staff
```

Number two: rename "staff" field to "is_staff", it would be righter

Answer (score 0):

It should be
is_staff
but not staff...
You can have it working if you type staff or change the model field to
is_staff.